# ASP.NET MVC Controller parameter processing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parameters, replace, controller

In my application I have a string parameter called "shop" that is required in all controllers, but it needs to be transformed using code like this:

```
        shop = shop.Replace("-", " ").ToLower();
```

How can I do this globally for all controllers without repeating this line in over and over?
Thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a [custom action filter](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/mvc/tutorial-14-cs.aspx), override `OnActionExecuting()` and apply the filter to all your controllers.  (Or simply overriding `OnActionExecuting()` in your base controller, if you have a base controller at all.)  The action method would look something like this:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var parameters = filterContext.ActionParameters;
    object shop;
    if (parameters.TryGetValue("shop", out shop))
    {
        parameters["shop"] = ((string)shop).Replace("-", " ").ToLower();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Buu, it worked great!
This solution removed 31 redundant lines of code in my app!
Leo