# ASP.NET MVC controller actions with custom parameter conversion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, onactionexecuting

I want to set up a ASP.NET MVC route that looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}/{idl}", // URL with parameters
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", idl = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

That routes requests that look like this...

```
Example/GetItems/1,2,3
```

...to my controller action:

```
public class ExampleController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetItems(List<int> id_list)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The question is, what do I set up to transform the `idl` url parameter from a `string` into `List<int>` and call the appropriate controller action?

I have seen a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570490/asp-net-mvc-controller-parameter-processing) that used `OnActionExecuting` to preprocess a string, but did not change the type. I don't think that will work for me here, because when I override `OnActionExecuting` in my controller and inspect the `ActionExecutingContext` parameter, I see that the `ActionParameters` dictionary already has an `idl` key with a null value- presumably, an attempted cast from string to `List<int>`... this is the part of the routing I want to be in control of.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A nice version is to implement your own Model Binder. You can find a sample [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/08/29/how-to-use-the-asp-net-mvc-modelbinder.aspx)

I try to give you an idea:

```
public class MyListBinder : IModelBinder
{   
     public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     {   
        string integers = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["idl"] as string;
        string [] stringArray = integers.Split(',');
        var list = new List<int>();
        foreach (string s in stringArray)
        {
           list.Add(int.Parse(s));
        }
        return list;  
     }  
}


public ActionResult GetItems([ModelBinder(typeof(MyListBinder))]List<int> id_list) 
{ 
    return View(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like slfan's says, a custom model binder is the way to go. Here's a another approach [from my blog](http://blog.nathan-taylor.net/2011/11/comma-separated-values-model-binder.html) which is generic and supports multiples data types. It also elegantly falls back to default the model binding implementation:

```
public class CommaSeparatedValuesModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo ToArrayMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("ToArray");

    protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable).Name) != null)
        {
            var actualValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(propertyDescriptor.Name);

            if (actualValue != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(actualValue.AttemptedValue) && actualValue.AttemptedValue.Contains(","))
            {
                var valueType = propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.GetElementType() ?? propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();

                if (valueType != null && valueType.GetInterface(typeof(IConvertible).Name) != null)
                {
                    var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(valueType));

                    foreach (var splitValue in actualValue.AttemptedValue.Split(new[] { ',' }))
                    {
                        list.Add(Convert.ChangeType(splitValue, valueType));
                    }

                    if (propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.IsArray)
                    {
                        return ToArrayMethod.MakeGenericMethod(valueType).Invoke(this, new[] { list });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return list;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
    }
}
```