# ASP.NET MVC3 Thousand separator in a decimal field is not recognized when user submits form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, submit, decimal, form-submit

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC3 application, and I have a form where user have to enter a price. For improving user experience, I'd like to implement a thousand separator. I've done it, you can see it working **[on this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/68adW/)**.

BUT

This Price field is part of a model and is declared in my Model file as

```
public decimal? Price {get; set;}
```

When I submit my form, `Price` is always `null`. However, it has the value entered in the form if I remove my thousand separator. This is because `Price` seems to be interpreted as a string, and not as a decimal, so MVC doesn't match the two properties (I suppose).

So, how can force MVC to recognize my value as a correct decimal and submit a model with the price entered by the user ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it will be easier to make the following: you can either create a hidden field on the form and store **the number without separators** or you can remove separators right before submitting the form.

Example:

```
$("#target-form").submit(function(event) {
  value_with_separators = $('.thousandSeparator').val();
  clean_value = value_with_separators.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  $('.thousandSeparator').val(clean_value);
});
```

There's also another way. You can implement custom `ModelBinder` and perform required conversions there. Here is a link to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406773/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-with-custom-parameter-conversion) with code samples.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok thank you for your snippet, it works correctly ! Thanks again !